# Windows command FOR in batch file, specified to work in a certain folder

Tags: for-loop

Normally I can specify a folder for a batch file to work in.

Not so with the FOR command:

`for %%a in (G_*.txt) do ren "%%a" "test-%%a"`

This finds **G_*.txt** in all files and renames those by putting **test-** in front of the filename.

I tried specifying **G_*.txt** further with **C:\test\G_*.txt** but that is not accepted.
I also tried pouring this into a variable but that also failed.

Who knows what to do?

Comment: I found a part of the solution. The targeted path goes into the first rename part:

`for %%a in (G_*.txt) do ren "C:\test\%%a" "test-%%a"`

Now I just need to pour that path part into a variable.

Comment: I was wrong about For. It only works in the current directory. It should be possible to point it to a specific path but that method made my script fail. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I had to change the approach: using SET /R will put a long path into the %%a variable which makes the idea unsuited to put a bit of text in front of a filename.

I found the solution by selecting the work directory first and let the FOR construction do its work. Since it must be network proof, I had to use the PUSHD command.
This is what the final result looks like:

```
set source=\\nassie\home\test\source with nasty space
set target=D:\target

PUSHD %source%
:: If this fails then exit
If %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto:eof

for %%a in (G_*.txt) do xcopy "%source%\%%a" "%target%\textblabla_%%a*" /D /Y

POPD
```